# gradle signingconfigs not found

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

In my application I want create debug and release build types

Here is my gradle code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pmbo.android.pmb"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 10001
        versionName "1.0"
    }


    signingConfigs {
        myConfigs{
            storeFile file("ncv.jks");
            storePassword("qwerty");
            keyAlias("MyNewApp");
            keyPassword("qwerty");
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig singningConfigs.myConfigs

        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
}
```

Everytime I try to build gradle I have this error

```
Error:(30, 0) Could not find property 'singningConfigs' on BuildType_Decorated{name=release, debuggable=false, testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false, pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false, renderscriptOptimLevel=3, applicationIdSuffix=null, versionNameSuffix=null, minifyEnabled=false, zipAlignEnabled=true, signingConfig=null, embedMicroApp=true, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[/Users/pmb/opt/sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt, /Users/pmb/Documents/MyProjects/PMBO/app/proguard-rules.pro], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}}.
```

I don't what I did wrong but looked everywhere and couldn't figure out what's the problem here.

My .jks file in my app module as shown in that picture. 
[image]

Could anyone just tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Error:(30, 0) Could not find property 'singningConfigs' on
```

Note that the property in the error message is `singningConfigs`. The real property is `signingConfigs`. Change:

```
signingConfig singningConfigs.myConfigs
```

to:

```
signingConfig signingConfigs.myConfigs
```

Comment: wow... how I did not notice this. thank you very much I changed it and it works thank you @CommonsWare as always you're great.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gradle experimental 0.7, you can use the following way to create signature:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.model.application"

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig = $("android.signingConfigs.myConfig")
            }
        }
    }
    android.signingConfigs {
        create("myConfig") {
            storeFile "/path/to/debug.keystore"
            storePassword "android"
            keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
            keyPassword "android"
            storeType "jks"
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this help those who uses gradle experimental versions.

Answer (score 0):

try to change 
    signingConfig singningConfigs.myConfigs

to
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release